# statements in jdbc

Tags: jdbc

does statement object contain the session id the database returns for the current session? What does a resultset
contain?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a session in the context of JDBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no, [`Statement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)s do not have session IDs. It seems like the [Java API specifications for the `Statement` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) backs that up. Basically, `Statement`s are used to execute SQL statements by specifying a SQL query through the [`execute`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) method.

A [`ResultSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is used to retrieve results which are returned by executing a query via a `Statement` or [`PreparedStatement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

The [JDBC(TM) Database Access](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) trail of [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) contains some information on these topics. The following sections may be of interest:

- [Lesson: JDBC Basics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

  - [Updating Tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/updating.html)
  - [Retrieving Values from Result Sets](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)